# Proof Verification of squeeze theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification, real-numbers

Theorem:If $X=(x_n)$, $Z=(z_n)$ and $Y=(y_n)$ be three given sequences such that
$$x_n\leq y_n\leq z_n\space for\space all \space n\in \mathbb N$$ and $lim(x_n)=lim(z_n)$.Show that  $Y$ is convergent and has limit $lim(x_n)$.
Proof: We see that $0 \leq y_n-x_n \leq z_n-x_n$ and thus $|(y_n-x_n)-0|\leq |z_n-x_n|$.
$lim(z_n-x_n)=lim(z_n)-lim(x_n)=0$ and thus,for every $\varepsilon>0$ we can find $K\in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n \geq K$ such that $|(y_n-x_n)-0|\leq |(z_n-x_n)-0|<\varepsilon$ and thus,$lim(y_n-x_n)=0$. Let $A=(y_n-x_n)$.We see that the sequence $A+X$ is convergent and further by algebra of limits,we get
$$lim \space A+X=lim(y_n-x_n+x_n)=lim(y_n)=lim(y_n-x_n)+lim(x_n)=0+lim(x_n)=lim(x_n)$$.
I doubt there is an glitch in the last part of my proof.Please let me know if it is correct or not.

Comment: I would write the last part as
$$
\lim y_n = \lim (y_n-z_n+z_n)=\lim (y_n-z_n) + \lim z_n=\lim z_n=\lim x_n.
$$

Comment: Small technicality: you should get $|(y_n-\color{red}{x_n})-0|\leq |z_n-x_n|$. But you can obtain $$|(y_n-z_n)-0|\leq |(y_n-x_n)-0|+|z_n-x_n| \leq 2|z_n-x_n|$$ by the triangle inequality; so everything would still work. Or you could flip around the starting inequalities.

Comment: Thank you @Dave. I have edited that part.